# Windows Phone 7 read and parse XML data from web service

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, windows-phone-7

I want these XML values read from the web service to a `TextBlock`, but this code causes a `NullReferenceException`. I'm sure from that the web service is not null. How can I solve this problem???

The line that causes the exception is commented and is:

```
// NOTE: NullReferenceException happens here
penalty = resultElements.Element("penalty").Value;
```

**Code**

```
namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public partial class pun : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        WebClient pu;

        public pun()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pu = new WebClient();

            string pp ="http://82.212.89.6:888/mob/resources/punishments/studentPunishments/427400078/2";
            pu.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(pp));

            pu.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(pun_DownloadStringCompleted);
            pu.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(pun_DownloadProgressChanged);
        }

        void pun_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.UserState as string == "mobiforge")
            {
                textBlock1.Text = e.BytesReceived.ToString() + " bytes received.";
            }
        }

        void pun_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
            {
                XElement resultElements = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

                // NOTE: NullReferenceException happens here
                penalty = resultElements.Element("penalty").Value;
                semester = resultElements.Element("semester").Value;

                pun1.Text = penalty;
                ps1.Text = semester;
           }

        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage tt = e.Content as MainPage;
            if (tt != null)
            {
                textBlock1.Text = tt.txtb1.Text;
            }
        }

        public string penalty { get; set; }
        public string semester { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which lines results in the NullReferenceException? What is the stacktrace?

Comment: penalty = resultElements.Element("penalty").Value;
          semester = resultElements.Element("semester").Value;  here is the exception occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me

```
penalty = resultElements.Element("studentPunishmentsTable").Element("penalty").Value;
semester = resultElements.Element("studentPunishmentsTable").Element("semester").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this WS a REST based one?? If so consider using RestSharp.